# Best way to call executable and get output in python

Tags: python

First a simple example to illustrate the situation. First the source .cpp that has been compiled into an executable:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This file has been made into an exe. Now in python it is called as follows:

```
import subprocess
import sys

sys.path.append('C:\Foo\Bar')

output = subprocess.Popen("hello_world.exe", stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

print output.stdout.read()
```

So this works fine for calling the executable and returning an output from the standard output. The question is, is there any feasible way to perform this to return potentially large arrays? From what I understand this is basically like returning and reading a text file, which would be quite slow! While I know SWIG or Cython are options for extending python with C++, I would find separate executable for each function more organized and modular!

TLDR: Can you return large arrays from executables back to python at a reasonable speed? Or is extending with Cython/SWIG/ctypes the only way to go?

Comment: you can read in a pretty darn huge textfile pretty fast (at least by human time)... its typically the proccessing that takes longer(especially if your matrix is too big to fit in memory)

Comment: To put it into context the point of the executable is to offload some heavy operations into c++ where the required loops will run faster. Then to return the processed array back to python. Arrays should be small enough to fit in memory, its just the calculations that will take the time. Efficient passing of the array from and to python will be necessary.

Comment: passing the arrays even as a text block should be a very small fraction of the execution time ... really I think you are over optimizing... how many elements are in this array?

Comment: I suppose I caused confusion by saying "large" without qualification. What I meant was "not tiny". This will be for a real-time image processing application where some loops in the code will be speed critical and done in c++ for improved performance. For array size I will estimate (640x480).

Comment: you will almost certainly want to write a wrapper in swig ... or just do it in numpy ... I would be curious at the timing differences between c and numpy (certainly c is faster but really how much, and why are you using python at all if you are worried about a few cpu cycles(and depending on what your doing numpy may be even faster with some of its tricks))

Comment: From previous work I have found numpy not fast enough for my applications. I guess I will just have to wrap in swig. As for why python, the main bulk of the program is much faster to develop in python. Only for the few loops do I need to offload to c++ for computation.

Comment: again Id be interested to see the speed difference ... and am surprised it would make any difference at all to the user ... without knowing what kind of manipulations and loops your doing its hard to say ... maybe you do get significant speed boosts (although I cant imagine if your bottleneck is reading a 640x480 file )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

1. subprocess.check_output or similar will return the entire program output as a string
2. subprocess.popen and incrementally read.

In the 1st scenario the output must fit in ram, otherwise very bad things will happen. In the second scenario you can set the buffer size and your subprocess should then halt until you read from the buffer at which point it will continue again.

cython/swig etc. etc. do nothing to reduce the memory footprint. If this is memory bound then you most likely want to use python and incrementally read/write to disk. Python is very efficient at passing around memory (i.e. it will not do eleventy seven memory copies unless you tell it to do that).

Comment: The problem is not so much with memory, arrays should fit in memory. It is more to do with offloading heavy calculations to c++ where they will run faster, then returning the array back to python for use. The question here is the speed of passing the array back.

Comment: If it makes sense for you to call an executable, the pipe overhead is not that bad. You may also be able to send binary data and use struct.unpack from python to handle it. If you want to directly call C libraries, numpy/scipy/weave may help in avoiding the need to write a real wrapper.